# Extract multidimensional array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm dealing with this array, but the key [row_204] changes each time (ie sometimes it is [row_79] or [row_109]) but all other key names stay the same in this exact structure. I need to get the value of UUID and userID but can't find a solution to get the value by key in that [row_] array.

I need to be able to extract the values and place them in strings, for example,

$uuid =

and so on.

I can't seem to find a similar query and have tried so many variations. Many thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
[action] => edit
[data] => Array
    (
        [row_204] => Array
            (
                [UUID] => 148367FF-FBEB-413D-8495-6B1539BDC5DC
                [userID] => 7
                [maxPoints] => 7
                [awardedPoints] => 6
                [Date] => 2017-06-08
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Is it always only one entry? e.g. only one `row_*` key?

Comment: Hi, yes. The above structure is identical in each case, just the row_ value changes

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is always only one `row_*` item in that array, you can just pull the first item (i.e., the only one in your case) off the front of the list with `array_shift()`:

```
$data = array_shift($array['data']);
print_r($data);
```

Will give you:

```
Array (
    [UUID] => 148367FF-FBEB-413D-8495-6B1539BDC5DC
    [userID] => 7
    [maxPoints] => 7
    [awardedPoints] => 6
    [Date] => 2017-06-08
)
```

Then you can just deference the keys you want:

```
$uuid = $data['UUID'];
```

Comment: Thanks for sucha speedy reply. The whole array is arriving in the form of a $_POST. When I use $data = array_unshift($_POST['data']); I get an error PHP Warning:  array_unshift() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: That was an error, it is `array_shift()`, not `array_unshift()`, @Alex Howansky already corrected it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, heh, I always get those backwards. My brain wants to think of something spelled "un-" as destructive, not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be:

```
$data = current($_POST['data']);
```

Then just `echo $data['UUID'];`.

If you need the key for whatever reason:

```
list($key, $data) = each($_POST['data']);
```